# Using NodeNext TypeScript module resolution, how do I import a file of the same name as a module?

Tags: typescript

I have a file `knip.ts` in a root directory of a workspace.

That file imports `knip`.

```
import { type KnipConfig } from 'knip';

const config: KnipConfig = {};

export default config;
```

Normally, that would reference the types of the package in `node_modules`.

However, using [`NodeNext` module resolution](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#node16-nodenext), this import resolves to the file itself, rather than the module, i.e.

[image]

so how do I import the module?

Note: I cannot change the name of the file (`knip.ts`)